# Better approach to Close the form on pressing escape key

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to close my form when pressing escape key on the form . I have found two solutions and both are working fine . as a beginner i am unable to found out the difference between the below two approaches . Can anyone explain me the difference between the following two approaches so that someone other can learn .

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

 **or the below one** 

    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (Form.ModifierKeys == Keys.None && keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
```

Comment: [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26160666/14171304).

Answer (score 0):

in your case I assume the `ProcessDialogKey` is the better choice

as is mentioned in this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processdialogkey?view=windowsdesktop-5.0

> This method is called during message preprocessing to handle dialog characters, such as TAB, RETURN, ESC, and arrow keys. This method is called only if the IsInputKey method indicates that the control is not processing the key.

you can also find the doc about `ProcessCmdKey` here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey?view=windowsdesktop-5.0

Comment: Sir , This is the problem only . I want to know about the explanation not defination which your link has provided. I am unable to understand the difference between two .